# IIS7.5 app error

Tags: .net, iis-7.5, badimageformatexception

I get this message when I tray to reach my web site

Empty assembly simple name.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Empty assembly simple name.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[BadImageFormatException: Empty assembly simple name.]

[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Abstractions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]

System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnInit(EventArgs e) +0

System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +333

System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210

System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210

System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +378

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5485; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5491

I have 2 servers and the site works on one server but not on the other

please help

Comment: Compare the application pools of the site in both servers, check the .net framewrok version

Comment: I did. they are the same